# DropDown list disappearing before user can the move mouse pointer to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu with list items Home and Home 2. When I hover my mouse over "Home"/"Home 2", the dropdown list appears for the item as expected. However, when I am moving my mouse down to the dropdown list, the list disappears immediately and I cant get access to the dropdown menu.

**I want the drop down list to be visible while moving my mouse down to the dropdown list** preferably using jQuery. However, I cant get it to work.

The HTML Layout for the design is:

> ```
>  <ul class="mega">
>     <li class="grid">Home
>         <ul>
>             <li>DD Item 1</li>
>             <li>DD Item 2</li>
>             <li>DD Item 3</li>
>         </ul>
>     </li>
>     <li class="grid">Home2
>         <div class="dropDownClass"">
>             <ul>
>                 <li>DD Item 4</li>
>                 <li>DD Item 5</li>
>                 <li>DD Item 6</li>
>             </ul>
>         </div>
>     </li> </ul>
> ```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

HTML:

```
<ul class="mega">
<li class="grid">Home
    <ul>
        <li>DD Item 1</li>
        <li>DD Item 2</li>
        <li>DD Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="grid">Home2
    <ul>
        <li>DD Item 4</li>
        <li>DD Item 5</li>
        <li>DD Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.mega{
    width: 200px;
}

.grid{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color:gray; 
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid ul{
    display: none;
}

.grid:hover > ul{
    display: inline;
}
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0db7v59a/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `document.ready` function:

```
 $('.grid1 ul').hide();   
    $('.grid2 ul').hide();  
    $('.grid1').on('mouseover', function() {
        $('.grid1 ul').show();
    $('.grid1').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.grid1 ul').hide();
    });
    });

    $('.grid2').on('mouseover', function() {
        $('.grid2 ul').show();
    $('.grid2').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.grid2 ul').hide();
    });
    });
```

and change the value of the class attributes of the two `<li>` elements from both being `grid` to one of them being `grid1` and the other being `grid2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your CSS to resemble this:

```
ul{list-style: none; padding: 3px; margin:0}   
li ul{display:none;}
li.grid:hover ul{display:block}
```

This will hide the second ul until the li is hovered.